# SPFx Modal open with a regular html button in datatables.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables, spfx

I´m using this solution in order to open modals in my React SPFx webpart, the problem is I have to open this modal from a Button in a datatable (datatables.net), since the OnClick() don't exist, only onclick() I'm having a problem calling the modal.

Is it possible put it to work?

This is the Modal link sample
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/modal-popup-in-spfx/

In the datatables I tried

```
{
    data: null,
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<input type="button" class="name" id=n-"' + meta.row + '" value="Edit"/>&nbsp<input type="button" class="salary" id=s-"' + meta.row + '" value="Delete"/>';
}
```

Then

```
that = this;
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.name', function () {
  var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
  that.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal myprops={that.state} handler={that.handler} />
});
```

But is expected working like this

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<ICertificatesListProps> {
    return (
      <div>
       ......


<Button onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e)} variant="contained" color="primary" style={{ float: "right" }}>Add +</Button>
{this.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
```

Handler

```
 handler() {
    this.setState({
      callchildcomponent: false
    });
  }
```

Kidnly ask the community for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment:

```
  that.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal myprops={that.state} handler={that.handler} />
```

may only work inside of the render function, as far as I understand. So you need to put in the render function, like in your "stock" example with the standard button. I would do that, and inside your button handler, would put something like this instead:

```
that.setState({
      callchildcomponent: true
    });
```

Comment: COOL ```that = this;
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.name', function () {
  var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
  that.setState({
 callchildcomponent: true
  });
});```